# Can I omit "[Emphasis mine]"?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Do I have to state "[Emphasis mine]" every time I highlight the relevant part of a quote with formatting? Can I omit it at all?

For example:

[image]

Comment: I often put [emphasis mine] or [bold added] *at the end of the quote itself*, so that it doesn't add the extra line breaks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not required.

Saying [emphasis mine] is simply a way to indicate that something you quoted is not entirely true to the original … or you might add it as a way to draw the readers' attention back to the relevant portions you highlighted for a specific purpose (i.e. parts that are not highlighted in the original quote).

Answer (score 7):

As Robert Cartaino said, you don't have to include that note.

Personally, I usually include the "emphasis mine" in the preceding text. Watch as I quote what you said, emphasis mine:

> Do I have to state `[Emphasis mine]` **every time** I highlight the relevant part of a quote with formatting? Can I omit it at all?

Another option, depending on the structure of that preceding sentence, is to parenthesize the "emphasis mine" rather than setting it off with a comma.

Once you have one such note in your post, I think most people will infer that additional formatting later in your post is also added by you.